# All possible combinations based on condition and apply a solver in python?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
Amounts   Type    Target
500        1       380
200        1       380
100        2       380
200        2       380
```

and I need to figure out which combination of `Amounts` of different types (say for example, 500 of type 1 and 200 of type 2) will result in the target value after a weighted average of 60/40.

For example:

0.6 * 500 + 0.4 * 200 = 380 so the combination 500 and 200 should return True.

I thought about a loop that multiplies each row with the another to produce all possible combinations (conditionally on `Type`), but not sure how to make itertools conditional on another column?

I also only wish to return the combinations of rows that return True, maybe identifiable by index or an ID column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This would be quite inefficient.

If you consider 500 units of type 2 and a target of 380, you know that you need (380 - 0.6 x 500) / 0.4 = 200 units of type 2. Hence dictionaries of amounts for each type is much better.